# Power View connect to SSAS Tabular

Tags: ssas

I have SSAS cube and I want to create report in Power View using connection to my Tabular cube. And I get error, can not connect.
is it possible to create powerview from SSAS Tabular ? or is there another way ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you can. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230973(v=sql.120).aspx
Pelase post error, connection info and version

Comment: so I must have sharepoint to do this

Comment: No, you can do it with Excel. https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-a-Power-View-sheet-connected-to-an-external-data-model-in-Excel-a721eb07-159e-488d-bcb1-804eb86040e0?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming Excel 2013 and the Power View add-in already enabled. Please follow the instructions [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Connect-to-or-import-data-from-SQL-Server-Analysis-Services-b6dd7f39-bea5-4e98-9aa1-39fc7b24424b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1) but on step 13 choose Power View instead of PivotTable.